# Facing issue while installing ruby-2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-2.7

I am facing issues while installing the latest ruby version 2.7.1

When I try to run the command `rvm install 2.7.1`

```
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.10', you are using older version '1.29.9'.
You can disable this warning with:   echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable auto-update with:     echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can update manually with:        rvm get VERSION                         (e.g. 'rvm get stable')

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/18.04/x86_64/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system........There has been an error while updating your system using `apt-get`.
It seems that there are some 404 Not Found errors for repositories listed in:

.    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\
Make sure that all repositories are available from your system and verify your setup by running manually:

    sudo apt-get update
-
Make sure that it works correctly before proceeding with RVM.
|
If you are working from the GUI instead of the terminal, you might want to verify and fix broken
repositories using "Software & Updates" application.
.
.
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.7.1',
please read /home/anikettiwari/.rvm/log/1592545564_ruby-2.7.1/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

When I try to run sudo apt-get update. It didn't help either

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                    
Hit:2 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                           
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                         
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                            
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sethj/silentcast/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                      
Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                
Hit:11 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:12 https://dbeaver.io/debs/dbeaver-ce  InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Hit:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                  
Hit:15 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                            
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sethj/silentcast/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done                       
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/sethj/silentcast/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
```

I try to check the logs as mentioned

```
cat /home/anikettiwari/.rvm/log/1592547152_ruby-2.7.1/update_system.log


[2020-06-19 11:42:32] requirements_debian_update_system
requirements_debian_update_system () 
{ 
    __rvm_try_sudo apt-get --quiet --yes update || { 
        \typeset __ret=$?;
        case ${__ret} in 
            100)
                rvm_error "There has been an error while updating your system using \`apt-get\`.
It seems that there are some 404 Not Found errors for repositories listed in:

    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

Make sure that all repositories are available from your system and verify your setup by running manually:

    sudo apt-get update

Make sure that it works correctly before proceeding with RVM.

If you are working from the GUI instead of the terminal, you might want to verify and fix broken
repositories using \"Software & Updates\" application.
"
            ;;
        esac;
        return ${__ret}
    }
}
current path: /home/anikettiwari/Desktop
GEM_HOME=/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3
GEM_PATH=/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global
PATH=/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/bin:/home/anikettiwari/anaconda3/condabin:/home/anikettiwari/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
command(2): requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.7.1
++ __rvm_try_sudo apt-get --quiet --yes update
++ typeset -a command_to_run
++ typeset sudo_path sbin_path missing_paths
++ command_to_run=("$@")
++ ((  UID == 0  ))
++ case "$rvm_autolibs_flag_number" in
++ is_a_function __rvm_sudo
++ typeset -f __rvm_sudo
++ missing_paths=
++ for sbin_path in /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/sbin
++ [[ -d /sbin ]]
++ [[ :/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/bin:/home/anikettiwari/anaconda3/condabin:/home/anikettiwari/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: != *\:\/\s\b\i\n\:* ]]
++ for sbin_path in /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/sbin
++ [[ -d /usr/sbin ]]
++ [[ :/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/bin:/home/anikettiwari/anaconda3/condabin:/home/anikettiwari/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: != *\:\/\u\s\r\/\s\b\i\n\:* ]]
++ for sbin_path in /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/sbin
++ [[ -d /usr/local/sbin ]]
++ [[ :/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/anikettiwari/.rvm/bin:/home/anikettiwari/anaconda3/condabin:/home/anikettiwari/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: != *\:\/\u\s\r\/\l\o\c\a\l\/\s\b\i\n\:* ]]
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ command_to_run=(__rvm_sudo -p "%p password required for '$*': " "${command_to_run[@]}")
++ __rvm_sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' apt-get --quiet --yes update
++ command sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' apt-get --quiet --yes update
++ sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' apt-get --quiet --yes update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sethj/silentcast/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic InRelease
Hit:14 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:15 https://dbeaver.io/debs/dbeaver-ce  InRelease
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sethj/silentcast/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/sethj/silentcast/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
++ return 100
++ typeset __ret=100
++ case ${__ret} in
++ rvm_error 'There has been an error while updating your system using `apt-get`.
It seems that there are some 404 Not Found errors for repositories listed in:

    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

Make sure that all repositories are available from your system and verify your setup by running manually:

    sudo apt-get update

Make sure that it works correctly before proceeding with RVM.

If you are working from the GUI instead of the terminal, you might want to verify and fix broken
repositories using "Software & Updates" application.
'
++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There has been an error while updating your system using `apt-get`.
It seems that there are some 404 Not Found errors for repositories listed in:

    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

Make sure that all repositories are available from your system and verify your setup by running manually:

    sudo apt-get update

Make sure that it works correctly before proceeding with RVM.

If you are working from the GUI instead of the terminal, you might want to verify and fix broken
repositories using "Software & Updates" application.
\n'
++ return 100
```

I am bit puzzled right now what needs to be done in order to resolve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is: [ppa:sethj/silentcast](https://launchpad.net/~sethj/+archive/ubuntu/silentcast)

This PPA is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic).

To remove it run:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:sethj/silentcast
```

Also, you may find this guide useful: [Best GIF Recorder Tools for Linux](https://itsfoss.com/best-gif-recorder-linux).

Answer (score 2):

I got the Similar Error But while Installing diffrent version of ruby `2.3.4`

[image]

I got the suggestion that Run following command to fix it up

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But that didnt work either i started getting issue in that

[image]

For fix it up i  comment on the line that causing the issue in the list

Formate of command will be like this  sudo nano path/*.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

it will open all the files one by one  and then comment the line and save the list

> ```
> <pre>Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release </pre>
> ```

[image]

after the save file when i run again update comamnd it work like a charm
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me

```
$ rvm autolibs homebrew
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
rvm autolibs read-only
```

for ubuntu 18.04 use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me

`rvm autolibs homebrew`
`rvm autolibs read-only`